# Find the first repeated letter in a string and the times it is repeated

Tags: python, string

I have the following string: "WPCOPEO" and I need to find the first repeated letter and the times it is repeated. I would appreciate some help with the coding.

```
string = "WPCOPEO"
def is_repeated(letter):
    for letter in String:
        if letter == letter
            print (letter)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Is this homework? What's your thought about this question?

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty easy if you think about it

check if element exists in set else insert into set

```
>>> s=set()
>>> for i in string:
...     if i in s:
...             c=i
...             break
...     else:
...             s.add(i)
... 
>>> c
'P'
>>> string.count(c)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

### One of the way getting it using list comprehension is given below:

```
word = "WPCOPEO"

print (next([letter, word.count(letter)] for pos, letter in enumerate(word) if letter in word[pos+1:]))
```

### Using for loop:

```
for pos, letter in enumerate(word):
    if letter in word[pos+1:]:
        print (letter, word.count(letter))
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the appearance by first storing each letters initial appearance with its frequency.

```
{'O': [3, 2], 'E': [4, 1], 'P': [1, 2], 'W': [0, 1], 'C': [2, 1]}
```

Next, you can transform that into a list of (appearance, letter frequency).

```
[[0, 'W', 1], [1, 'P', 2], [2, 'C', 1], [3, 'O', 2], [4, 'E', 1]]
```

Then you can sort by frequency and appearance and grab the first item.

```
[[1, 'P', 2], [3, 'O', 2], [0, 'W', 1], [2, 'C', 1], [4, 'E', 1]]
```

---

### Example

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

def letter_frequency_by_initial_pos(word):
  occurs = {}
  first_appearance = 0
  for letter in word:
    if letter in occurs:
      occurs[letter][1] += 1
    else:
      occurs[letter] = [ first_appearance, 1 ]
      first_appearance += 1  
  return occurs

def appearance_to_frequency(occurs):
  freq_by_appearance = [None] * len(occurs)
  for letter in occurs:
    freq_by_appearance[occurs[letter][0]] = [ occurs[letter][0], letter, occurs[letter][1] ]
  return sorted(freq_by_appearance, key = lambda x: (-x[2], x[0], x[1]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  freq = appearance_to_frequency(letter_frequency_by_initial_pos('WPCOPEO'))
  print('The letter {} appears {} times.'.format(freq[0][1], freq[0][2]))
```

**Output:**

> The letter P appears 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_repeated(string):
    for i in range(1,len(string)):
        check=string[0]
        if check == string[i]:
            print("This character is frequent:",string[i])

string = "WPCOPEO"
is_repeated(string)
```

Comment: It would be nice if you add a little explanation along with your code. Also, it doesn't seem to solve the OP problem.